# PowerShell Get-WinEvent EndTime Parameter problem

Tags: powershell, get-winevent

using:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="application";starttime="8/10/2022 10:00:00"}
```

works perfectly, but: (and there are records in this time span for sure!)

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="application";starttime="8/10/2022 10:00:00";EndTime="8/11/2022 10:00:00"}
```

brings a message: no events were found.
What is wrong?

Comment: Try `EndTime=Get-Date -Month 8 -Day 11 -Year 2022 -Hour 10 -Minute 00 -Second 00`

Comment: thanks, it works, but it's a ... cumbersome approach, why doesn't work with the date format like "starttime"?